# How do you access/modify a JFrame object from a different class?

Tags: java, swing, textbox, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to create a code that will create a text box inside of the JFrame object and then after a button is clicked, the text inside the box will change.  I am still confused on how to create the text box and also how I could edit it from inside the other class.  Everything I have tried so far won't work due to the lack of ability to access the JFrame from a separate class.  This is what I have so far.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BlackjackGUI{
public static void main(String[] args){

JFrame frame= new JFrame("Blackjack");
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(400, 500);
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);
JButton hit=new JButton("Hit");
panel.add(hit);
hit.addActionListener(new Action());
//make text box
}

static class Action extends BlackjackGUI implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

    //code to edit text in text box




    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- First and foremost: get **most** of that code out of the static main method. Your JFrame is *buried* in the main method making it and its child components inaccessible. Your goal is to have two **objects** interact, and this will require that you create well-behaved OOP-compliant classes. So do that -- create classes with fields, such as a JTextArea field if need be, with public accessor and mutator methods, with constructors.
- Yes you will need a main method, but its purpose should be to create the main actors, allow them to connect somehow (say by passing one as a parameter into the other), and then setting the program in motion. It should do little else.
- Next and also very important: don't use inheritance for this purpose since inheritance is not used to allow one class to communicate with another (at least not as you're using it). For example, having your 2nd class inherit from BlackjackGUI will serve no useful purpose.
- Instead **composition** is the key. Have one class hold a field of the other type and assign to it the correct viable reference, and voilà, you're all set.